# How do you find the effects of external shocks in stock time series?

Tags: time-series

I have to identify 4 different points in time per stock price. I have several thousand stock prices, which are available as a monthly time series, so I need an automated calculation of the points in time per stock.

I am investigating the effects of external shocks, e.g. COVID-19 or the financial crisis, on companies' share prices. Therefore, I have already determined the relevant time period, but each company reacts to these shocks at different points in time (one to two months earlier or later).

The points in time I need to find are: Te (start of disruption), Td (price stops to degrade), Ts (start of recovery),Tf (end of recovery). Te describes the point in time at which the share price collapses. Td is the point in time at which the share price stops falling and stabilizes at a certain level and Ts is the point in time at which the share price rises again in the long term. Tf is the time at which the share price equals the price at Te.

How do I determine Te, Td, and Ts? Is it best to use Change Point Detection, Topological Data Analysis or another procedure?

My analysis is done in R. I am not doing a prediction but an ex-post analysis.